# Passing pointers to functions with and without &

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to understand when I need to use the address-of operator `&` when passing arguments by reference (for readers that mind my imprecision please read this as *simulate pass-by-reference*) to functions without modifying the function itself. I will give two small examples using `struct`s. In both the `struct` is passed by reference but one involves the usage of `&` and the other does not. The explanation in this particular case will probably involve the usage of `malloc()` in the second example and I can guess it but I would like a more experienced opinion. Futhermore, my question is more general: Is there a rule (or a rule-of-thumb at least) when I can pass by reference without using `&`?

Example 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Author {
        char *Name;
        int Born;
        int Died;
        char *Notable_Works;
};

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann);

int main()
{
        struct Author thomas_mann;
        thomas_mann.Name = "Thomas Mann";
        thomas_mann.Born = 1875;
        thomas_mann.Died = 1955;
        thomas_mann.Notable_Works = "Der Zauberberg";

        print_struct(&thomas_mann);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann)
{
        printf("%s was born in %d and died in %d.\n",
                        thomas_mann->Name, thomas_mann->Born, thomas_mann->Died);
        printf("His most notable work includes ‘%s’.\n",
                        thomas_mann->Notable_Works);
}
```

Example 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Author {
        char *Name;
        int Born;
        int Died;
        char *Notable_Works;
};

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann);

int main()
{
        struct Author *thomas_mann = malloc(sizeof(struct Author));
        if (!thomas_mann) {
                fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        thomas_mann->Name = "Thomas Mann";
        thomas_mann->Born = 1875;
        thomas_mann->Died = 1955;
        thomas_mann->Notable_Works = "Der Zauberberg";

        print_struct(thomas_mann);

        free(thomas_mann);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann)
{
        printf("%s was born in %d and died in %d.\n",
               thomas_mann->Name, thomas_mann->Born, thomas_mann->Died);
        printf("His most notable work includes ‘%s’.\n",
               thomas_mann->Notable_Works);
}
```

Comment: You don't have an "option" whether to pass `x` or `&x` (and there's no rule of thump either). It depends on *type* expected by the function. In both of your examples, that's the *only* correct way to pass arguments (without modifying the function or changing the type in the caller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is really very simple.  You want to call a function that takes a pointer to a `struct` object.  If you *already have a pointer* to the object you want to use that function on, you don't need `&`.  Otherwise, you do.

What do I mean by "already have a pointer"?

```
struct Author *thomas_mann;
```

In this case, you already have a pointer, because the variable `thomas_mann` has type `struct Author *`, which is a pointer.  I have removed the initialization because *what you initialize this with doesn't matter;* it's a pointer already, because of its type.

```
struct Author thomas_mann;
```

In this case, you do not already have a pointer.  The variable `thomas_mann` has type `struct Author`, which is not a pointer type.

```
struct Author thomas_mann;
struct Author *p_thomas_mann = &thomas_mann;
```

In this case, you could call `print_struct` with either `p_thomas_mann` or `&thomas_mann` and the effect would be the same.

---

It's important to understand that *C does not have pass by reference*.  All function arguments, regardless of their type, are passed by *value*.<sup>1</sup>  The function `print_struct`'s argument is passed by value.  That value happens to be a *pointer* to a struct object, and it can therefore be *used* similarly to how a reference-argument would be used in a language that had pass by reference, but it is not actually a reference in the language-theoretic sense.  (It *is* a "reference" as that word is casually used in English, though.  Your confusion is understandable, but you must move beyond it to become fluent in C.)

<sup>1</sup> You may see people talking about "pass by invisible reference" but unless you are implementing a C compiler, or something that has to interoperate at the assembly level with the C calling convention, you do not need to worry about this, because it's invisible.

---

There is an additional wrinkle:

```
struct Author a_thomas_mann[1];
```

*This* variable has type "array of `struct Author`".  Because it has an array type, `a_thomas_mann` will be treated as syntactic sugar for `&a_thomas_mann[0]` in most, but not all, contexts.  This is called *type decay* and it can mislead people into thinking that C does have pass by reference.  Again, it doesn't.  It has an odd bit of syntactic sugar relating only to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First, in C, all arguments are passed by value, although you could use a pointer to simulate *pass by reference*, as what `print_struct` does in your example.

Whether using `&` or not depends on the type. The function `print_struct` expects a pointer to `struct Author` as its argument. In the first example, `thomas_mann` is of type `struct Author`, so you need `&thomas_mann` which is a pointer to `struct Author`. In the second example, `thomas_mann` is of type `struct Author *`, so you don't need `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The following quote comes from [Yu Haos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30648680/1989425)... I don't believe I can do better in addressing this aspect of the question.

> First, in C, all arguments are passed by value, although you could use a pointer to simulate *pass by reference*, as what `print_struct` does in your example.
>
> Whether using `&` or not depends on the type. The function `print_struct` expects a pointer to `struct Author` as its argument. In the first example, `thomas_mann` is of type `struct Author`, so you need `&thomas_mann` which is a pointer to `struct Author`. In the second example, `thomas_mann` is of type `struct Author *`, so you don't need `&` operator.

It seems as though Yu Hao has forgotten to address an example which you haven't provided, however.

> Is there a rule (or a rule-of-thumb at least) when I can pass by reference without using `&`?

Aside from the aforementioned, when an array is used in an expression other than a `sizeof` or `&`address-of expression, it will be silently converted to a pointer. Hence, consider this example #3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Author {
        char *Name;
        int Born;
        int Died;
        char *Notable_Works;
};

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann);

int main()
{
        struct Author thomas_mann[] = { { .Name = "Thomas Mann"
                                        , .Born = 1875
                                        , .Died = 1955;
                                        , .Notable_Works = "Der Zauberberg" } };

        print_struct(thomas_mann);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_struct(struct Author *thomas_mann)
{
        printf("%s was born in %d and died in %d.\n",
               thomas_mann->Name, thomas_mann->Born, thomas_mann->Died);
        printf("His most notable work includes ‘%s’.\n",
               thomas_mann->Notable_Works);
}
```

... or heck, if you wanted to condense it even further you could remove `thomas_mann` from `main` and just call `print_struct` like so:

```
print_struct((struct Author[]){ { .Name = "Thomas Mann"
                                , .Born = 1875
                                , .Died = 1955;
                                , .Notable_Works = "Der Zauberberg" } });
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass by reference, you need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to pass. In your first example, you have a `struct Author` that you want to pass. To pass a pointer to that, you need its address, so you need to use the `&` operator. In your second example, you have a `struct Author*`. This is already a pointer to the `struct Author` you want to pass, so you can just pass the pointer itself.

The main difference between the two approaches is whether you have allocated on the stack or the heap. In #1, you allocated the `struct Author` on the stack, but in #2, you allocated it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator is not the `pass-by-reference` operator in C, only in C++.
In example 1 you are passing the address of an instance of the `Author` struct to the function `print_struct`.

In example 2 you are directly passing a pointer that points to an instance of the `Author` struct to the function `print_struct`.

Both examples do exactly the same thing in this case but example 2 requires the programmer to be more alert because of heap allocation with `malloc` instead of stack allocation. If you don't intend to use an object outside the scope of the function it was made in I would suggest using Example 1 since the object will be cleaned up after it goes out of scope. This is not the case with Example 2 and may leak to memory leaks when not paying attention.

Comment: I wouldn't call the & a pass-by-reference operator even in C++. There also it is the address-of operator. It is just that in the type part of declarations and definitions, the & is used to indicate (in the same place where a * for pointer would go), that it is a reference.